# Как установить свой дизайн для значка в google maps, используя возможности html?

Tags: css3, google-maps-api, html, javascript

Здравствуйте. 
В картах Google есть возможность ставить свой собственный маркер вместо стандартного. Для этого надо указать url на свою картинку. 
Но что делать, если надо возможность делать дизайн маркера более широкая? Иными словами, как сделать так, чтобы установить вместо стандартного маркера не картинку, а собственный HTML-код, где будет что угодно?

Comment: например, что может быть маркером вместо маркера?

Comment: <DIV>И тут свой свобственный дазайн иконки с применением html, css.</DIV>

Comment: ну вот если там в апи функционал разрешает добавить ТОЛЬКО картинки, я не думаю что туда можно вставить что-то другое, да и вряд ли там, на маркере, есть HTML. разве что можно javascript его ловить и нацеплять что-то поверх

Comment: ДА! То, что надо! Переведите комментарий в ответ.

Comment: Перевел...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На счет html я не уверен, но точно можно попробовать canvas'ом рисовать поверх карт. [Пруфлинки](http://mabp.kiev.ua/tag/google/).

Answer (score 0):

Я добавлял в объявление карты вот такой код:

```
 markers: [{ latitude: 41.655242, longitude: 12.989615, 
            icon: "/img/icon-2s.png"}]
```

ПРимер использования можно посмотреть на сайте http://www.primavera-italy.ru/map/

Comment: Не, не подходит. Если надо использовать группу иконок, чтобы получить конечный маркер в зависимости от параметров, то этот метод не подойдет. Надо что-то, что бы формировало одну картинку из нескольких. Предложенная идея @ling 'ом на основе `canvas`, оказалось тем, чем надо, хотя по ссылке ничего полезного я не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

для начала добавляем изображение маркера в папку сайта

```
   var icon_1 = 'google_map_icon/Arrow_1.png"; ?>';
```

потом передаем ссылку на маркер

```
   markers.push([ location.city + ", " + location.region ,lat, lng ,icon_1]);
```

и при добавлении маркеров в цикле мы создаем маркер с нашей картинкой

```
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                title: markers[i][0],
                icon: {
                url: markers[i][3] ,
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(64, 64)
                }
   });
```

вот так будет выглядеть код поиска и вывода координат из базы в цикле

```
                <div id="regions_div" style="width: 100%; height: 350px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var markers = [],infoWindowContent = [];
            jQuery(function($) {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaRw&hl=en&callback=initialize";
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            });

            function initialize() {
                var map;
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                var mapOptions = {
                    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("regions_div"), mapOptions);
                map.setTilt(45);

                <?php
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT location FROM response WHERE location LIKE '%\"loc\":\"%' GROUP BY location ")->result_array();

                foreach($query as $row){
                $replace = '';
                $string = $row['user_location'];
                $string = ereg_replace("'", $replace, $string);
                $row['user_location'] = $string;
                ?>
                var icon_1 = 'http://www.bla.bla/Arrow_1.png"; ?>';

                try{
                    var location = JSON.parse('<?php echo $row['user_location'] ?>');
                    var lat  = location.loc.split(",")[0];
                    var lng  = location.loc.split(",")[1];

                    markers.push([ location.city + ", " + location.region ,lat, lng ,icon_1]);
                    infoWindowContent.push(
                        ['<div class="info_content">' +
                        '<h3> '+ location.city + ", " + location.region + ' </h3>' +
                        '</div>']);
                }catch(e){
                    console.log("JSON Parse Error");
                }
                <?php } ?>
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
                if(markers.length){
                    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
                        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: position,
                            map: map,
                            title: markers[i][0],
                            icon: {
                            url: markers[i][3] ,
                            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(64, 64)
                            }
                        });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                            return function() {
                                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, i));
                        map.setCenter(position);
                        map.setZoom(2);
                    }
                }else{
                    var pos = {
                        lat: -34.397,
                        lng: 150.644
                    };
                    map.setCenter(pos);
                    map.setZoom(3);
                }

            }
        </script>
```